# Is there a list or pattern of overriding control themes?

Tags: android, themes

I know that you can globally set control themes using a styles.xml and referencing a theme for activities.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/SecondaryColor</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/PrimaryTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/datepicker</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/textView</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/spinner</item>
        <item name="android:checkBoxStyle">@style/CheckboxStyle</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="datepicker">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/SecondaryColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/SpinnerBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="textView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/defaultTextViewSize</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogThemeButton">
        <item name="android:background">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogThemeTextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/PrimaryTextColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownStyle" parent="android:Widget.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/SpinnerDivider</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CheckBoxStyle" parent="android:Widget.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/SpinnerDivider</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/PrimaryTextColor</item>

        <!--        <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/DialogThemeTextAppearance</item>-->
        <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/DialogThemeButton</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Question:

Is there some way to find the appropriate item names for any kind of control?

I think i should be able to find it on google using my question, but i cannot.

Answer (score 0):

A strict pattern would have been nice but i guess that'll do:

GitHub Sources:

- https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml
- https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

Google Sources:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml